# how to align 4 text input fields in html in the form of a staircase?

Tags: html, css

This is something which I want using CSS, not using tables and rows

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the input field is active only along the vertical projection of first text box.

Suggestions are needed.

Comment: Please post your code in your question

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps necessary to coding what you want:

1. Create four `input` elements
2. Give them each a `width` property of `25%`
3. Give the first one a `margin-right` property of `0%`
4. Give the second one a `margin-right` property of `25%`
5. Give the third one a `margin-right` property of `50%`
6. Give the fourth one a `margin-right` property of `75%`
7. Add a `<br>` tag after each element to make them all appear on new lines

Hope this helps, please provide a coded example of what you've tried if this isn't sufficient info to help.